# ViewerSupport ComboViewer, how to bind a List<Long>?

Tags: java, data-binding, combobox, swt, jface

This question seems to be very easy, but I have no clue how to do this.
Lets assume this short snippet :

```
List<Long> model = new ArrayList<Long>();
model.add(Long.valueOf(1d));
model.add(Long.valueOf(2d));
model.add(Long.valueOf(3d));
WritableList list = new WritableList(model, Long.class);

comboViewer = new ComboViewer(composite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ObservableListContentProvider());
ViewerSupport.bind(comboViewer, list, ???);
```

what do I have to insert as third parameter in the ViewerSupport.bind to simply show the numbers in the ComboViewer ?

Usually there have to be something like "BeanProperties.values(new String[] { "name" })" but I want the toString() getter of Long to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your ComboViewer in the following manner:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;

/*
 * model - your model object
 * modelAttrName - List<Long> attribute name, within your model
 * toModel, fromModel - update value strategies. can be jsut new UpdateValueStrategy() in 
 * the beginning
*/
public static Binding bindCombo(DataBindingContext bindingContext, Object model, String modelAttrName, UpdateValueStrategy toModel, UpdateValueStrategy fromModel) {

Combo combo = comboViewer.getCombo();

return dataBindingContext.bindValue(WidgetProperties.selection().observe(combo),
    BeansObservables.observeValue(model, modelAttrName), toModel, fromModel);

}
```

Your model then should look like this:

```
class MyModel {

private List<Long> longs;

// provide getters and setters for logs class and fire property change events, using property change support

}
```

You would use it like this:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
bindCombo(new DataBindingContext(), model, "longs", new UpdateValueStrategy(), new UpdateValueStrategy());
```

Comment: And what do I have to provide as "modelAttrName" ? I think thats the problem, the attribute I need of Long.class is just the toString() method. Of course I could subclass Long and provide a string getter and set the attribute name but that kind of ugly overhead I think.